# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push' when adding to JSON in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to create a a simple shopping cart stored in localStorage as JSON, but I get this error when submitting the form to add item to cart.

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'push' cart.js:11

Here's my script.

```
var cart = {"cart": {"tuote":{"id":"2", "count": "4"}}};

localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(cart));

var localCart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
console.log(localCart.cart.tuote.id);

$("#addToCart").on("submit",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var update = localCart.cart.push(
        {"tuote":{"id":"2", "count": "4"}}
    );

    localStorage.setItem('cart',JSON.stringify(update));

    var uusiKori = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));

    for(var i=0; i < uusiKori.cart.length; i++){
        console.log(uusiKori.cart.tuote.id);
    }
});
```

So, it adds an entry named `cart` with a value `{"cart":{"tuote":{"id":"2","count":"4"}}}` to localStorage, and logs `id`in the console.

But if I try adding an item to cart, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

[A fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/LTFjU/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't push into an object, but into an array.

You might want to change the cart structure into something like this:

```
var cart = {"cart": [ {"tuote":{"id":"2", "count": "4"}} ] };
```

And then, to add to this cart, you'd do:

```
cart.cart.push(newStuff);
```

(of course, you're fetching your cart from localStorage, but the principle is the same)

Comment: Is it still valid JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is. Arrays are fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var cart = {"cart": {"tuote":{"id":"2", "count": "4"}}};
```

`cart` is not an array instead it is an Object. You may change your base JSON like below

```
var cart = {"cart": [{"tuote":{"id":"2", "count": "4"}}]};
```