# Remove json inside an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've a json string stored in local storage, which could look like this:

```
{
   "cart":[
      {
         "tuote":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Rengas 1",
            "count":"2",
            "price":"8"
         }
      },
      {
         "tuote":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Rengas 2",
            "count":"4",
            "price":"8"
         }
      },
      {
         "tuote":{
            "id":"3",
            "name":"Rengas 3",
            "count":"4",
            "price":"8"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

So, let's say I want to remove **Rengas 2**, with id **2** (it's the middle one in this case.)

I know, I could use splice and do it like this

```
myJson.splice(2,1);
```

But what if I have hundreds of items in the array?

And I won't know which one I want to remove (clicking a button in this case would remove the item), how would I do that?

---

So if I want to remove the item that I click on, in this case.

[image: this]

Comment: Your only real choice (if you don't know it's index) is to iterate over the array till you find the one you want and remove it.

Comment: It would likely be easier to handle if your cart instead held an object where the keys are item ids so that you can get to a specific item by id without having to iterate.

Comment: Assuming you can't restructure your data, @KevinB is correct. If you *can* restructure your data, I would consider making your cart be a plain object instead of an array and map the items by ID.

Comment: Would there be more than one item to remove?

Comment: Just one item at a time @Jack

Comment: @acbabis Could you give me an example? How could I add items to that then, if I can't use .push? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22045435/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-push-when-adding-to-json-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there's only one element to be removed at a time:

```
var pos = -1;
var cart = myJson.cart;
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    if (cart[i].tuote.name == "Rengas 2") {
        pos = i;
        break;
    }
}
if (pos > -1) {
    cart.splice(pos, 1);
}
```

Comment: Same as @Jack solution. Wouldn't it be a problem if there's another item with tuote.name Rengas 2? As it's possible.

Comment: Read the first line of my answer -- I said this only works if you're only removing one item.

Comment: Well, I only want to remove one item ;) But if there's two items with the same name (or id, doesn't matter) something is going to fail? My guess is that the first one gets removed.

Comment: Yes, this will remove the first one.

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try! :)

Answer (score 0):

You would pull your JSON from local and assign it to a variable

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("yourKey"));
```

Iterate on the property you want to find:

```
var id = 2;
for (var i = 0; i < myObject.cart.length; i++) {
    if (myObject.cart[i].tuote.id == id) {
        myObject.cart[i].splice(i, 1);
        //break; //only use if you want to kill the loop after the first found result
    }
}
```

And `splice`!

Comment: Splicing while you're looping will skip elements, unless you count _down_ instead of up.

Comment: @Barmar Or unless you `break;` after the first removal ... or decrement the loop variable when you splice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse the condition and use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/):

```
var toRemove = 'Rengas 2';

data.cart = $.grep(data.cart, function(item) {
    return item.name != toRemove;
});
```

If you're already using native storage you can probably also use [`[].filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure your data, this design might better support the operations you're trying to do:

```
{
   "cart":{
      "1":{
         "tuote":{
            "id":"1",
            "name":"Rengas 1",
            "count":"2",
            "price":"8"
         }
      },
      "2":{
         "tuote":{
            "id":"2",
            "name":"Rengas 2",
            "count":"4",
            "price":"8"
         }
      },
      "3":{
         "tuote":{
            "id":"3",
            "name":"Rengas 3",
            "count":"4",
            "price":"8"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

To add another item:

```
var newObj = {
    "tuote":{
        "id":"7",
        "name":"Rengas 1",
        "count":"2",
        "price":"8"
    };
...
myJSON[newObj.toute.id] = newObj;
```

To delete a specific item:

```
myJSON[7] = undefined;
```

To make this work, you just need to store each ID in your table rows, so that you can get the ID when trying to delete.

Comment: Storing an id in table rows isn't a problem ;) I'll try this! But how do I add the ascending number every time?

Comment: @Christian If you're using a database, you can use the ID of the item in the database. If you have no such IDs in your server, you can keep a running counter of items you've made with your JS. Each time you make a new item, increment the global counter.